# Jenkins declarative pipeline. Triggering child job with number of parrent one

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have declarative pipeline which trigger job

```
phase_IB: {
    build (
      job: 'workflow_jobs/integration_build_gitlab',
      parameters: [
        string(name: 'BUILD_NUMBER', value: "${BUILD_NUMBER}"),
        string(name: 'BranchName', value: "${gitlabSourceBranchCadEx}"),
        string(name: 'SubmoduleBranchName', value: "${gitlabSourceBranchSM}"),
...
      ],
      propagate: true, quietPeriod: 15
    )
    sleep 1
},
```

I would like to launch child job with the same number as parent
But I not understatnd what way to do it.
I tried pass BUILD_NUMBER But it does not work